# Can we sleep while fasting on Ekadashi?

Tags: vishnu, fasting, vrata

According to various Vaishnava web sites and various texts, during Ekadashi, one cannot sleep in the night, one cannot sleep during the wee morning hours, and one cannot sleep during the day or else one breaks the fast and there is no merit. So when can we sleep? Are we even allowed to sleep on Ekadashi?

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto It's because all of the contradictory information confuses me. I'll remove it.

Comment: Sure, it can happen with anyone. FYI sleeping is not made for daytime. It's always about night.

Comment: Most devotees, who are fasting on that day, sleep during nite time.. but some most staunch devotees may keep vigil at nite.. @Viper91

Comment: @Rickross When the scriptures state at "night", they mean like up to 12:00 AM, right? Since at/after 12 AM, is morning. But I think Hindu scriptures have a different definition of what is day and night. Anyways, I fasted since the start of the Ekadashi tithi, read the Kamada Ekadashi story, did some japa, and went to bed at 2 AM. Woke up at 5:15 AM for Brahmamuhurtha. I asked Lord Vishnu to forgive me for any mistakes I may have committed. I will break the fast tomorrow (3/28/18) at/after 6:50 AM, as stated on Drik Panchang.

My parents said that devotion and sincerity is what matters most.

Comment: Viper91 12:00 am around time is called ArdhaRatri (mid night) . In Hindu Scriptures a day starts with Sunrise and ends with Sun rise of next day. So night means from around 8 pm to 4-5 am , if sun rises at 6 am.

Comment: Viper91 AM does not mean "morning" . Even in a normal life, we do not say 1 am as morning, it is still a night. Morning is the time round sun rise, like from 5 am to 8 am . AM means ante meridiem  meaning before noon time. Noon time is usually arpund 12 Pm , therefore from 12 am to 11:59 am is called AM as it is before noon (12 PM) and time from 12 pm to 11:59 pm is called PM as it is after noon time (I.e. after 12 pm time) . AM does not mean morning. Morning means time around sun rise, I.e. around 5 am to 8 am

Comment: No they do not mean that.. "Ratri jagaran" means keeping vigil the whole nite like devotees do during Shiva Ratri nite.. But for the Ekadashi fasts, afaik, not doing so does not ruin the fast.. one can sleep at nite. @Viper91

Comment: @Rickross Thanks. But if you look at some Vaishnava sites and some Vaishna texts, they clearly states that one should not sleep during the night or during the day while fasting on Ekadashi or on the morning of Dwadashi or else all merits are lost. There's so much contractions and no consensus.

This is why I agree with the Aghori Vimalananda in the "Aghora Series" when he states that corrupt Brahmans have ruined Hinduism by making up complex rules and regulations, most of it for their own selfish benefit. That originally, Hindu rituals and practices were easy and simple, but yet powerful.

Comment: Ok.. i am not aware of any such injunctions (that fast is ruined unless u remain awake at nite).. but may be there.. u can wait for some answers.. it is not ok to sleep during the day time ..that much i know. @Viper91 BTW it took me a while to realise that u are Maharex :D

Comment: @Rickross Yes, I know that sleeping during the day is prohibited in Hinduism, although some texts states that this sin can be nullified by simply chanting the Gayatri mantra.

I'm just going to continue doing what I have always been doing, keep fast during ekadashi, chant and do japa at night and go to bed after 12 AM.

Yes, I was previously Maha Rex. Still trying to find that quote about a man with many enemies must be great.

Answer (score 5):

According to  [**Skanda Purana**](https://drive.google.com/drive/mobile/folders/0Bwu-vE3n9ze9fnlVRmlPVjVKWDJnTjEzaXJycS1mNllIa3NqcjZwMUEtZUpVMTc4X0ZEQUU?usp=sharing)  **Part six -Book Two - Vaishnav Kanda -Section five - Margashirsha Mahatmya -Chapter 13.Importance of Jagrana during Ekadashi Vrata**,  One should not sleep during both during  day or  night in  Ekadashi Vrata.

Skanda Purana gives the possible explanation of this as follows.

> जागरं ये च कुर्वंति कर्मणा मनसा गिरा ।।
>  न तेषां पुनरावृत्तिर्मम
> लोकात्कथंचन ।। 43 ।।
>
> 43 Those who observed Jagrana mentally , verbally and physically do
> not return from my world.

That means the devotees who keep this Vrata and do not sleep during day or night , do not get rebirth on this earth. As already mentioned in that chapter those who perform this vrata get merged with lord as mentioned by he himself.

The purana says because life is  transitory ,man get's rebirth on this earth. As day and nights are  also  transitory .But those who stay awake during both day and night do escape this transition.

> प्राप्ताप्येकादशी येषां कलौ जागरणं विना ।।
>  ते विनष्टा न संदेहो
> यस्माज्जीवितमध्रुवम् ।। 9 ।।
>
> 9 Those who observe  ekadashi vrata without Jagrana in kali age
> without Jagrana are ruined , there is no doubt about it ,because life
> is Transitory.

---

Conclusion - Those who is observing the Ekadashi Vrata are not allowed to sleep during entire day or night at all ,because that will ruin the fruits of observing this Vrata of getting salvation , and one will again be reborn , if he failed to do so.

Comment: Wow Very Brilliant answer. @Viper91 kindly tick it as it will be useful for other users and readers also.

Comment: I know that, but my question is, when can we sleep then? Are you saying that we cannot sleep for 24 hrs+?

Comment: Yes , that is what it is. Because if one has to escape the cycle of birth and death ,one must stay awake and pray to Vishnu borh in day and night during that day.

Comment: @SwiftPushkar Lol. Lord Vishnu also states that extreme tapas that causes, or can lead to health problems, is tamastic — in the mode of ignorance.

I generally do not take most of the Puranas seriously.

Comment: @Viper91 - I think staying awake and doing Puja-Archana etc. just for 24 hours isn't "Extreme Tapa" and can cause serious health problems. Infact in whole of the year devotees are asked to fully stay awake both during day & night in devotion just once. i.e. just for one day.

Comment: That is the least difficult task assigned ,with none of the side effects. And the outcome is extraordinary.

Comment: @SwiftPushkar Probably for Sanyasis, but do these people have a job? Lol. And it's not for one day, it's more than 24 hours. Your not allowed to sleep during the morning on Dvdashi.

Comment: Have u ever performed this vrata urself? @SwiftPushkar

Comment: @SwiftPushkar Yes, I have been doing Ekadashi vrat for the last two years.I also fast on the new moon and full moon days. My family and I are predominately Vaishnavas; we mainly worship Lord Vishnu and Maha Lakshmi, but we see all the Devas and Devis as manifestations of the same source. We are vegetarians who do not eat any onions and garlic, we do not drink alcohol or smoke. We are not from India and we are not members of any temples and we do not have any religious leader.This is why I depend on sites like these and the internet for information. I study as many Hindu texts as possible.

Comment: @Viper91 - It's really good that you are following Dharma. Nice to know that.

Comment: As par First Ekadashi vrata katha, When Mata Ekadashi asked boon of ekadashi fasts from Lord Vishnu then She stated that fruit of Ekadashi vrata will be devided in two parts. Half in day and half fruit in night. Those who will keep awake at night will get full and other will get half fruits. So think again on your answer pls since it may lead or miss-lead devotees.

Comment: @Rishabh - There will be no misleading occur here , as I am directly quoting from purana. Of Course will will find various versions in various texts  , its quite not possible to ascertain the best or the right one. I will try to update the answer if i came across the version mention by you.

Answer (score 1):

Don't be tempted to drink water.
Stay on the path of the mala between your fingers.
Thinking about food removes your vrat and your pyunya if you're doing it for someone else.
Keep wrapped in a blanket.
Sit on your mat.
Know your deity.
Forget your reality,  this is your reality.
Keep onto the vedas, don't become pulled in by news and radio.
You're going to be a bit rough after this,  depending on how new you are to it. (I'm serious about the blanket, a body without food needs awareness to stay warm,  since you have not developed your awareness you'll need a blanket.)
If this is your path,  then you know the flaws of humanity are purposeful, Prakrti.
Ekadashi is your path to Purusha.
Good luck

Comment: Welcome to HSE! Kindly have a look at the help centre on how to answer questions as well as [Gudelines for new users](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125/guidelines-for-new-users-answering-questions). The site insists on backing up answers with sources, failing which the answers may be subject to deletion 15-30 days later